# Basic intuition behind proving Runge's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I am studying functional analysis and have a little bit of previous study in complex analysis. I want to prove Runge's theorem, but am finding it difficult to find a source that helps me understand exactly what is happening (especially due to the fact that many sources use different methods and different terminology).

**Runge's Theorem** *(The version I am interested in)* States that one can approximate a function which is holomorphic on
a compact set in $\mathbb{C}$ by rational functions with only one pole at a prescribed point in the complement of
the compact set.

I have seen that a Corollary of the Hahn Banach Theorem is very useful along with the Riesz Representation theorem.

H.B : *Conway (III) 6.13* :If **N** is a normed space and **M** is a linear subspace of **N** then,

Closure(**M**) = $\{ Ker f : f \in \bf{N'} \text{(dual space)}  \ \cap \ \ \bf{M}\subseteq Ker f \}$

For a locally compact topological space **X** let,
\begin{equation}
C_{0} (\bf{X}) = \{ f \in C(\bf{X},\mathbb{C}) \big | \forall \epsilon>0 : f^{-1} (\mathbb{C}\backslash B_{\epsilon}(0))  \ \ \text{Compact} \}
\end{equation}

(In Short) The Riesz Representation Theorem gives an interpretation of the dual $ C_{0} (\bf{X})'$
in terms of certain measures
on X.

*Riesz Representation Theorem (Appendix C) Conway* :

If **X** is a locally compact space and $ \mu \in $ The measures of **X**, define,$F_{\mu} :  C_{0} (\bf{X}) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by,

$F_{\mu} (f) = \int f d \mu $

Then,

$F_{\mu} \in  C_{0} (\bf{X})'$ and the map $\mu \rightarrow F_{\mu}$ is an isometric isomorphism of the measures of **X** onto $ C_{0} (\bf{X})'$.

I am confused with the notation. Here is a link to Conways book.http://www.faculty.jacobs-university.de/poswald/teaching/FunctAnal/handouts/John%20B.%20Conway%20A%20course%20in%20functional%20analysis%20%201997.pdf. Chapter (III) He calls $K$ the compact subset and $E$ the subset of $\mathbb{C}\backslash K$ He then  calls $R(K,E)$ the closure in the space $C(K)$ of the rational functions with poles in $E$.

Where I am stuck is understanding how he can say that (from the theorems I introduced above)all we need to prove Runge's theorem is  that,

if $\mu$ is a measure in $K$ and $\int g d \mu = 0$ for all $g \in R(K,E) $

then $\int f d \mu =0$.

I can follow the rest of the math in the proof in Conway but this is the key to the proof and I am finding it hard to understand. Can we relate this to $C_0(X)$?.The more books I look at the more notation I see, so I am just going to stick with this.

Comment: The version of the theorem you state is incorrect. You need one possible pole in each component of the complement of $K$.

Comment: That's how it appears in my notes. I understand your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $K$ is compact, $C_0(K)=C(K)$. Let $A$ be a Banach space and let $B$ be a subspace. Then $B$ is dense in $A$ if and only if every linear functional $\lambda$ on $A$ such that $\lambda(b)=0$ for all $b\in B$ is the zero functional on $A$. We apply this to the Banach space $A$ consisting of all functions which are uniform limits of functions holomorphic on $K$ and the subspace $R(K, E)$.

Disclaimer: I typed this on my phone, I will double check it later.

Edit (Later checking): The first result you quote (under the statement of Runge's theorem) is what I describe above.

Since $C_0(K)=C(K)$, and $A$ (as above) is a closed linear subspace (actually it is Banach algebra) of $C(K)$, it follows from the Riesz representation theorem that every linear functional on $A$ is represented by a measure on $K$. By the first result, it is enough to show that if $F_\mu$ (in your notation) is such that $F_\mu(g)=0$ for all $g\in R(X,E)$, where $E$ is chosen such that $\mathbb C\setminus E$ meets each component of $\mathbb C\setminus K$ at exactly one point, satisfies $F_\mu=0$. We must be careful here: this functional $F_\mu$ is not identically zero on $C(K)$ in general! (Not every continuous function on an arbirtary compact subset $X$ of $\mathbb C$ can be uniformly approximated by functions which are holomorphic on a neighbourhood of $X$.)

Comment: So we need to show $F_{\mu}(f)= 0 $, and this can only happen if the Cauchy transform, i.e $\hat \mu(w) = \int_{K} \frac{d \mu (z)}{w-z} = 0$ in all components $U$ in $\mathbb{C}\backslash K$.

Comment: Yes, the Cauchy transform of $\mu$ should vanish off $K$. You may wish to take a look at Gamelin *Uniform algebras*, chapter II for some of these details.

Comment: Is it because f is bounded and continuous anyways in C(K)?

Comment: This is fairly elementary by definition. It makes no sense to study the continuous functions which vanish at infinity for compact sets $K$ because there is no "infinity".

Comment: So also C_0(K)' is isomorphic to C_0(K)?

Comment: If you mean the dual space of $C_0(K)$ then no. The dual space is a vector space of complex, regular, Borel measures on $K$, by the Reisz representation theory.